# Swift: How to define a required Enum in a Protocol?

Tags: swift, enums, protocols

**Context**

Hi, I am working with `Protocols` and would like to require a specific `Enum` with predefined cases. However, I get the following `Error Message`:

> Type 'Category' cannot be nested in protocol 'Categorisable'

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Categorisable {
    enum Category {}
}

struct Entity: Categorisable {
    enum Category {
        case category1, category2, ...
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

1. How can I define a required `Enum` in a `Protocol`?
2. Is it possible to also define cases and other default implementations (e.g. computed variables)?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What problem are you trying to solve by achieving this?

Comment: Did you mean to include a property of that type in the protocol? `var category: Category { get set }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  No I am trying to force all conforming Structs to define an Enum called Category.

Comment: @Sweeper I am trying to force all conforming Structs to define an Enum called Category.

Comment: I know you are trying to do that, but *why* are you trying to do that? What problem does "forcing all conforming Structs to define an Enum called `Category`" solve?

Comment: @Sweeper to simplify the codebase. When simply requiring to a protocol adds this Enum, you don't have to define it separately in each Struct.

Comment: Oh, so you want each struct conforming to the protocol to have the *same* enum? If so, please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: So make up your mind is it one enum definition per type as you first claimed or one single enum definition for all conforming types according your last claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to share the same enum across all the structs conforming to `Categorisable`, you can declare the enum outside of the structs, and then declare a `typealias` in a protocol extension.

```
enum DefaultCategory: CategoryProtocol {
    case category1, category2, category3

    // computed properties go here...
}

extension Categorisable {
    typealias Category = DefaultCategory
}
```

---

If some of the conforming structs can have a different enum type in their implementation of the protocol (e.g. with more cases than required), then you should use an associated type. Constrain the associated type to a protocol that specifies the minimum cases you require.

Here is an example:

```
protocol Categorisable {
    associatedtype Category: CategoryProtocol = DefaultCategory
}

protocol CategoryProtocol {
    static var category1: Self { get }
    static var category2: Self { get }
    static var category3: Self { get }

    // computed properties go here...
}

enum DefaultCategory: CategoryProtocol {
    case category1, category2, category3

    // computed properties go here...
}

// Example of a struct using the default enum
struct ConformingStruct1: Categorisable {}

// Example of a struct using a custom enum
struct ConformingStruct2: Categorisable {
    enum Category: CategoryProtocol {
        // with some extra cases
        case category1, category2, category3, category4, category5

        // computed properties go here...
    }
}
```

Note that conforming structs aren't required to use enums to implement the categories. Conformers could also write a struct or classe, and write static properties to implement them.

Protocols only specify the interface - on the outside, you can't tell whether `Category.category1` is a static readonly property of a class or struct, or an enum case, can you? They all look the same "from the outside". The fact that you know it is implemented as an enum case is an implementation detail, and protocols cannot require that.